# How to get last_activity in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, timeout

My sessions in Codeigniter are timing out in less time than I specified in the "config/constants.php" file. I set that constant to 3600 seconds (one hour) but sometimes I get kicked out in 5 or 10 minutes. This happens in regular MVC calls, no ajax involved.

I'm trying to access the last_activity value in the CI session, but this is what the CI documentation currently states: "last_activity: Depends on the storage, no straightforward way. Sorry!"

So how can I access that value? Any ideas?

Here's some additional info:

```
    `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = EXPIRE_SESSION;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;'
```

Comment: I am not sure, but may be you can't get your constant value here in ```config.php```, please try once with hard-coded value : 3600

Comment: Not sure what this is sys_get_temp_dir() but save path some thing like `APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/';`

Comment: @kishor10d: Thanks for the reply. Executing "print '<pre>' . print_r($this->config, TRUE) . '</pre>';" tells me that I can in fact use constants in "config.php". Using the value "3600" or "EXPIRE_SESSION" (which is also 3600) is exactly the same.

Comment: @wolfgang1983: The function sys_get_temp_dir does just what it says, it outputs your system's temporary files directory. In my case it's "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp" and that location does have a lot of files and folders so it looks like it's working.

Comment: @PedroAraujoJorge I would not use that my self I would use a folder in application directory somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default session handling scheme, the last activity is the timestamp "column", or whatever it looks like in the session file. Should update every time you refresh a page. It may not update when you do something like access a modal or manipulate the page via AJAX, I haven't checked.

Here's what it looks like from the manual as a database insert:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Comment: Regarding database vs files for session data handling. The `session` methods work exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just did some tests and looks like "__ci_last_regenerate" is just storing the login date. It does not change when I go to some other page or controller and look at its value. It remains the same throughout the session. However I noticed that the date stored there does not take into account my timezone, which is GMT+01 (one hour later). Could it have something to do with this?

Comment: @PedroAraujoJorge I apologize for my completely stupid answer. The value I referenced is just the last time it refreshed the session ID. That was probably the single most wrong answer I've ever posted, sarcastic and meta answers not included. I apologize for any time you wasted on that.